# how to split classes correctly(OOP)?

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

Well i have got an Class that reads a Excel-file as template.

- The class converts the Excel File to a Java Object
- Adds Information to the template
- rewrites the Template with the added Informations

i was reading some stuff about the single-responsibility-principle and decided that i need to refactor my class, because its doing more than one thing.

iam just not sure if iam doing to much here ?

```
public class ExcelWorkbookCreator {
public Workbook create() 
}

public class ExcelToBean {
  public List<ExcelBean> convert(Workbook workbook);
  private void writeCellDataToBillingBean(ExcelBean excelBean, DataFormatter   dataformatter, Cell cell, int counter);
  private boolean isDatevalueFormattedCorrectly(String datevalue);
}

public class ExcelWriter {
  public void beanToExcel(List<ExcelBean> excelBeanList, Workbook workbook);
  public int write();
  private void fillValidationInformation(Sheet sheet, int rowCount, ExcelBean   excelBean);
  private void fillHeaderRow(Sheet sheet, int rowCount);
  private void autoSizeCoulmn(Sheet sheet);
}

public class ExcelUtils {
  public static boolean isHeaderRow(int rowNumber);
  public static boolean isCellEmpty(Cell cell);
  public static boolean isRowEmpty(Row row, DataFormatter dataformatter);
  public static void closeWorkbook(Workbook workbook);
}

//before i had all methods in One Class.
```

Comment: Are all theses class in the same file?

Comment: In my opinion you've got single responsibility wrong. Single responsibility says a module should have responsibility over one part of the system. Now it may do many things with that part doesn't mean it has violated single responsibility principle. What you are doing is instead trying to split the responsibility of one module amongst different modules/classes.

Comment: @ivange94 So in your opinion i would be fine if i have a class called "ExcelProcessor" with all the Mehods in it? In this way i would have a class which is only responsible for one Part of the Project and that is handling Excel operations...

Comment: Nice question btw! I wish more people would really think about the quality of their code that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design could be improved with regards to OOP. Whether it conforms to the ideas of SRP and SOLID should come distant second (or third) after you are confident with OOP.

The first thing that strikes me are the class names. Three of them describe an action rather than a "thing", and the 4th is a "Utils" class with static methods, which is a big no-no, if we are sticking with OOP.

So, let's choose the right names first. If your domain is about Excel, your classes should be: `ExcelFile`, `Sheet`, `Row`, `Cell`, etc. You have some of them already, which is good, but *all* the objects need to come from your Domain, specifically the "things" in your Domain.

If you have those, think about what they must do (the responsibilities) in order to get what you want at the end. Not the data they must have, but what *functionality* they might offer. I can imagine for example that `ExcelFile` has a method called `writeTo(File file)`, or a `Cell` has `isEmpty()`, etc.

You've done a good job, if your logic is a one-liner at the end, something like:

```java
ExcelFile.readFrom(...).addInformation(...).writeTo(...);
```

You should be able to read your requirements back from the code.

*If* you reach this point, *then* it makes sense to go over the code and see whether some object has maybe too many responsibilities that justifies a refactoring.

Comment: Verbs in class names can be fine when thinking about "services". Not everything must necessarily be about *things*. Sometimes it is much more about behavior and processing.

Answer (score 1):

From a first glance, this looks quite good to me.

The point is to have a *meaningful* amount of "responsibility" within a class/method. Just by reading the name of the class, and looking at the public methods it should be clear *what* that class can do for you, and *how* you interact with the class to actually get to these results.

Beyond that, methods should do something that is easy to test with unit tests.

Taking all the above ideas into account: yes, this looks good.

Where: I assume that your public static utility methods are used in more than one class, only then they should go into a distinct class. The only thing *worth* thinking about: do all the methods and classes need to be pubic? An external user of the overall solution (invoking it from a different package), does that client code really need *all* these public methods? Meaning: only make public what *external* client code is supposed to be using!